# Refering list in test class

Tags: unit-test

I have a class and a test class

```
public with sharing class Mem
{
    public List<User> lstCon{get;set;}

    public Mem()
    {
        lstCon = new List<User>();

        List<User> lstCurUser = [SELECT Id, ContactId, Contact.AccountId 
                                     FROM   User 
                                     WHERE  Id =: UserInfo.getUserId()
                                     AND    ContactId != null];

        iflstCurUser != null && lstCurUser.size() > 0)
        {
            Id AccountId = lstCurUser[0].Contact.AccountId;

            lstCon = [SELECT    Id, ContactId, Contact.Name, LastLoginDate 
                                          FROM      User 
                                          WHERE     IsActive=true 
                                          AND       contactId != null
                                          AND       IsPortalEnabled = true
                                          AND       contact.accountId = : accountId 
                                          AND       Id != :UserInfo.getUserId()];
        }
    }
}
```

Following is test class

```
    public with sharing class Mem_Test
{
    @IsTest(SeeAllData=true) public static void TestMem()
    {
        Mem controller= new Mem();
        Account acc = new Account(name='TestClient');
    insert acc;

    //Create and insert a contact
    Contact con = new Contact(LastName = 'TestConLN', FirstName = 'TestConFN', Email='test@testing.com', Grant_Access__c = true,AccountId=acc.Id);
    insert con;

    //Have a trigger defined to convert contact to portal user if Grant Access is true-- Hence inserting contact should fire a trigger and create portal user.
    //Getting the user created
    User u = [SELECT Id, ContactId, Contact.AccountId 
                 FROM   User 
                 WHERE  contactId = : con.Id];//This is returning null value??

    System.runAs(u) 
    {
        // The following code runs as user 'u' 
        System.debug('Current User: ' + UserInfo.getUserName());
        System.debug('Current Profile: ' + UserInfo.getProfileId()); 
       controller.lstCon;
    }   
    }
}
```

Getting error:- Limit has no rows of assignment to s object. When quering for User.
and also getting save error on controller.lstCon.
How to get the values in the list

Comment: did your trigger ran suceessfully.Go through logs to see was there user insertion ?

Comment: Actually.. the user license limit has extended... so it was not creating user... Its fine.. just can you please tell me how do i use the list in test class

Comment: Hey you are not inserting user there,without inserting you are querying

Answer (score 2):

It is likely the issue with your list is that its being initilised ahead of the user being created, since your logic is in the Mem class constructor. Move the constructor inside your System.runAs.

Try something like this...

```
System.runAs(u) 
{
    // The following code runs as user 'u' 
    System.debug('Current User: ' + UserInfo.getUserName());
    System.debug('Current Profile: ' + UserInfo.getProfileId()); 
    Mem controller = new Mem();
    System.assert(controller.lstCon.size()>0);
}
```